# Netty Connection In Thread Pool

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to send multiple packages to the server with using multiple threads. My goal is sending packages at a time. I am creating a thread pool before my function starts.

There is a producer thread which insert new packages into the queue and consumer thread (there are 10 of them) and consumer threads creates connection and sends the packages in the optimal scenario.

But in my scenario, it happens one by one.

```
private static BlockingQueue jobQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue(10);
private static Object lock = new Object();

ExecutorService producers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
ExecutorService consumers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

## PRODUCER THREAD

```
producers.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                int value = new Random().nextInt(20);
                System.out.println("Added to list: " + value);
                jobQueue.put(value);
            }
        });
```

## CONSUMER THREAD

```
consumers.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                if (!LB.getUpHostList().isEmpty()) {
                    Host host = LB.getUpHostList().get(0);

                    if (host.isActive()) {
                        String message;

                        message = jobQueue.take().toString();
                        System.out.println("Removed from list: " + message);

                        boolean isConnected = connect(host, message, 1);

                        if (!isConnected) {
                            System.out.println("SAVED");
                            jobQueue.put(Integer.parseInt(message));
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Consumer thread must work in a parallel way. I guess there should be a callable list in consumer thread but I didnt get that point

## CONNECT FUNCTION

```
public static boolean connect(Host host, String message, int mode) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap();

            clientBootstrap.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 100);

            clientBootstrap.group(group);
            clientBootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            clientBootstrap.remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host.getIp(), host.getPort()));

            clientBootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {

                    //TODO, TIMEOUT BILGISI ILE DOLDUR BURAYI
                    //socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(1));
                    //socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(2, 2, 4));

                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new FalconClientHandler(host, message, mode));
                }
            });

            ChannelFuture channelFuture = clientBootstrap.connect().sync();
            channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Connection timed out --> " + e);
            host.setActive(false); //connection kurulamadı demektir. Bir sonraki mesaj geldiğinde bu hostun açılıp açılmadığı denenecek.
            return false;
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
            if (mode == 0) { //arka planda sunucu hep ayakta olmalı. Mode 0 da asla bağlantı kesilmemeli. Kesiliyorsa host kapanmıştır.
                host.setActive(false);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to send one package a time, but in your case it is happening concurrently ? is this your question ??

Comment: Why don't you use the `BlockingQueue`?

Comment: Does blockingQueue provide doing producer / consumer operation without using syncronized operation?

Comment: @MukeshVerma, if there are 10 threads, im waiting to establish 10 connection at the same time. But in this case it is happening one by one

Comment: Your connect method might be creating only one connection. Could you show the code for connect method.I suspect whatever api/library here netty, is creating just one connection which is shared by all the consumers.I think in netty there is concept of channel pools for connection management.

Comment: I'll share it today. I am working on other business right now. Thanks

Comment: Just published...